# Install the command `list`

Tags: command-line, 16.10

By default, the `list` command is not installed on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. Could anyone be able to tell how could install this command?

The `list` command is related to the `mail` command, which could be installed with `sudo apt install mailutils`. In the NDG course, I got the following picture :

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us more about this `list` command? What does it do?

Comment: @fkraiem I've modified the question; I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` command you are looking for is not a shell command, but a command internal to the `mail` program. So you need to first run the `mail` command in your shell in order to run the `mail` program, and then you can use its `list` command:

```
firas@wakaba ~ % mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/firas": 1 message 1 unread
>U  1 firas@wakaba       Mon Nov 28 09:41   15/396   Test
& list
Commands are:
next, alias, print, type, Type, Print, visual, top, touch, preserve, 
delete, dp, dt, undelete, unset, mail, mbox, pipe, |, more, page, More, 
Page, unread, Unread, !, copy, chdir, cd, save, source, set, shell, 
version, group, write, from, file, folder, folders, ?, z, headers, 
help, =, Reply, Respond, reply, respond, edit, echo, quit, list, xit, 
exit, size, hold, if, else, endif, alternates, ignore, discard, retain, 
saveignore, savediscard, saveretain, #, inc, new
& quit
Held 1 message in /var/mail/firas
```

If `mail` just answers "no mail", you can send yourself a mail first:

```
firas@wakaba ~ % mail
No mail for firas
firas@wakaba ~ % echo "Test." | mail -s Test firas
firas@wakaba ~ % mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/firas": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 firas@wakaba       Mon Nov 28 09:42   14/386   Test
& list
Commands are:
next, alias, print, type, Type, Print, visual, top, touch, preserve, 
delete, dp, dt, undelete, unset, mail, mbox, pipe, |, more, page, More, 
Page, unread, Unread, !, copy, chdir, cd, save, source, set, shell, 
version, group, write, from, file, folder, folders, ?, z, headers, 
help, =, Reply, Respond, reply, respond, edit, echo, quit, list, xit, 
exit, size, hold, if, else, endif, alternates, ignore, discard, retain, 
saveignore, savediscard, saveretain, #, inc, new
& quit
Held 1 message in /var/mail/firas
```